# Modifying an xml attribute element with a value of a child element with lxml

Tags: python, regex, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I have an XML snippet like this:

```
<parent id="1">
    <child1>
        <child2>[content]I need to get[/content]Other text</child2>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

And I would like to add the [content] of "child1" as an attribute into the parent element.

Getting something like this:

```
<parent id="1" value = "I need to get">
    <child1>
        <child2>Other text</child2>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

I have this code, however it does not work as it looks like it only iters in the first child and does not go to the next.

```
pattern = re.compile('[content](.*?)[/content]')
xml_parser = et.parse(str(xml_file))
root_xml = xml_parser.getroot()
translatable_elements = root_xml.xpath('//parent')
for element in translatable_elements:
    for child_element in element.iterchildren():
        if child_element.tag == 'child1':
            source_content = child_element.text
            value_str = pattern.match(source_content).group(1)
            element.attrib['value'] = value_str
            source_content = pattern.sub(source_content,'')
    tree = et.ElementTree(root_xml)
 tree.write(str(xml_file), encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: `element.attrib['satt_note'] = notes_str` should be in the inner loop

Comment: What happens when multiple children have conflicting content?

Comment: Can you show what your code actually does that makes you unhappy with its behavior?

Comment: It only gets <child1> however the code is not able to access to <child2>

Comment: Is regex really the right tool to match `[content] ... [/content]`? Is this genuinely a text string? Or is that actually some nested XML, or HTML, or something else that can be parsed properly (i.e. not with regex)?

Comment: For example, could you have nested content, like: `[content] ... [context] ... [/content] ... [/content]`?

Comment: No, that would not happen.  [content]...[/content] Is genuinely a text string. it cannot be parsed as XML or HTML. And there would not be any nested content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the `re` with a proper regex escaped string. Also, you were trying to grab text from `child1` instead of `child2`. This should be along the lines you're looking:

```
import re
from lxml import etree

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)

    pattern = re.compile(r'\[content\](.*?)\[\/content\]')
    root = tree.getroot()
    pars = root.xpath('//parent')

    for par in pars:
        for child1 in par.iterchildren('child1'):
            child2 = child1.getchildren()[0]
            val = pattern.match(child2.text).group(1)
            par.set('value', val)
            child2.text = pattern.sub('', child2.text)

    print(etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to not use regex at all and use plain xpath.

Since you said your XML was a snippet, I wrapped it in a `doc` element and added another `parent` to show what happens when there are multiples.

Example...

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<doc>
    <parent id="1">
        <child1>
            <child2>[content]I need to get[/content]Other text</child2>
        </child1>
    </parent>
    <parent id="2">
        <child1>
            <child2>[content]I need to get this too[/content]More other text</child2>
        </child1>
    </parent>
</doc>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

for parent in tree.xpath(".//parent"):
    child2 = parent.xpath("./child1/child2")[0]
    parent.attrib["value"] = child2.xpath("substring-before(substring-after(.,'[content]'),'[/content]')")
    child2.text = child2.xpath("substring-after(.,'[/content]')")

tree.write("output.xml")
```

**Output** (output.xml)

```xml
<doc>
    <parent id="1" value="I need to get">
        <child1>
            <child2>Other text</child2>
        </child1>
    </parent>
    <parent id="2" value="I need to get this too">
        <child1>
            <child2>More other text</child2>
        </child1>
    </parent>
</doc>
```